# handling appDelegate in my app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS app development and near completion to developing my first app. So now begins the finishing work, which includes how my app should behave when it reaches certain events or states. I know the code to handle such tasks goes into `appDelegate.m` but I am kinda confused about what I am actually supposed to do. My app is simple, it triggers an animation with sound when a button is pressed and I want the sound to stop as soon as the user hits the home button. I tried this but in vain:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    finalViewController.AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID)
}
```

Besides my app also crashes when I press the home button sign twice and try to close my app. It gives me the `'signal SIGABRT'` error in `main.m`. Please help.

Comment: FWIW, the crash when you double-tap-x your app is expected behavior when attached to the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it in here instead:

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{}`

or maybe

`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{}`

Comment: no actually the issue is  it says "use of undeclared identifier `soundID`" even though I have exposed it as my property in my VC and I have imported my VC into my delegate.

Comment: `...WillTerminate:` is not a reasonable substitute for `...DidEnterBackground:` -- it means something different.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're getting an error like:

> use of undeclared identifier soundID

If `soundID` is a property of your app delegate, you should access it using property notation, like:

```
self.soundID
```

or:

```
[self soundID]
```

The "undeclared identifier" means that the compiler doesn't know what you're talking about when you say `soundID`. The instance variable that's backing that property probably has a different name (like `_soundID`), so `soundID` doesn't refer to the ivar itself, it's just the property name.

Comment: To add something based on the comments... If you have "imported" your view controller into the delegate and it has property `soundID` then you would access it by `nameOfViewController.soundID`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the given code snippet to stop the sound & access the `soundId` which you have passed in `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)`. You can create the `soundId` variable in `appDelegate` & save the `soundId` when you play the system sound.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID)
}
```